# Is there a way to compare char and string in c++?

Tags: string, c++11, char, compare

I am currently learning about file handling in c++. I want to check if the username that the user has entered in the beginning is the same as the one he enters in the end to write to a TXT file.

I tried running a loop and comparing the char array at index [0] with the string index[0].

code explaination: 
getuser - username entered in the beginning (String)

user - username entered now (char array)

```
char user[16];
for(int i = 0; i < getUser.length(); i++){
    if(!(user[i] == getUser[i])){
        cout << "enter right username!";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

I wanted the loop to check each character, if it right, it will continue, otherwise it will print an error message and exit with return 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `user` variable required to be a char array? If it is not you could use the `std::string` type and the `std::string::compare` method. It returns `0` if the strings match.

```cpp
std::string firstUser ("foo");
std::string secondUser ("bar");

if (firstUser.compare(secondUser) != 0) std::cout << "enter right username!";
else std::cout << "well done!";
```

The `compare` method has some interesting variations you should check [the reference here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/).

Comment: Yes, it has to be char. I am using ofstream to write that array to a text.

Comment: You can extract a c-style string from a std::string and you definitely don't have to use char arrays to use ofstream. Please provide some more details in your question.

Comment: @BrunoMacedo - with std::strings you don't need any extra comparison functions, just use the `==` operator overload. Of course, good to know there is also a dedicated function.